# SR650 - Raid 5 - HDD

Tags: raid, hdd

Last week one HDD went to critical status in RAID 5.
I was able to replace it and the rebuild started.
Everything went smoothly until today.

I wanted to replace that HDD because the size was not as the original one.
4TB -> 8TB rest is also 4 TB

And I carelessly pulled out the wrong
HDD and also marked the right one to be removed in XCC.

...
I know..

I plugged the two HDD back anyway and tried to make it work, but I cannot start the rebuild.
The HDD's can only to be set as Hot swappable to the RAID 5 array. /data/

Desperately asking someone the advice me on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, *two* disks went offline while the array was in operation. RAID 5 can only compensate *one* failed disk. The array has been destroyed.

Recreate the array from scratch and restore from backup. Alternatively hire a recovery service and be prepared to pay four to five digit fees.

Comment: I will get support, server has warranty. I think it cannot be resolved without dataloss. Will see tomorrow.

Comment: I was able to solve this without support. I used Manage foreign configuration option in xcc raid setup. The Slot 7 drive was outside of the raid array and in configured bad (foreign) state. After one click it added to raid and the rebuild started on slot 10 also.

Comment: Well, good luck with the rebuild, I hope there's only limited damage. In any case, if you've got no reliable and tested backup yet, now's the time to do it.

Comment: Rebuild went well. Everything is ok. It was a good experience in a way..  Thanks for your comment! 